# receiving response from page method using jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am calling page method using jquery. In examples every one receives a reply using result.d

for example:

```
 function onSuccess(msg)
      {
      alert("suc" + msg.d);          
      }
```

Please guide me what is this .d ?